# Sum of independent random variables is poisson

Tags: probability, compactness

If we have two independent variables $X_1, X_2$, $X_1+X_2\sim Poisson$, how can we prove $X_1, X_2$ are poisson?

Comment: [Raikov's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raikov%27s_theorem)

Comment: Note that the conclusion is that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are _shifted_ Poisson variables, because $X_1-\alpha$ and $X_2+\alpha$ work just as well for any real $\alpha$.